# How to add a sliding menu inside one of the tabs?

Tags: android, android-tabs, android-menu, android-sliding

My app has 3 tabs at the top ( Say A, B and C ). I want to add a sliding menu only inside A. It must not be accessed within tabs B and C.Also the menu should not cover the tabs. It should remain only inside Tab A. Can someone help me doing it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 3 tabs, it means that you have 3 fragments, one for each tab. Each fragment should have it's own XML layout file. You put the Menu inside the XML file of that specific tab, and there you go. I would be able to help you more if you posted some code.

Comment: @HarshPokharna You have all the info you should need right here :http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Comment: One another thing ! If i have 3 tabs , I will make 3 different activities for them, right? And each activity will have a different xml file, right ? But how do I link these tabs to the activities ?

Comment: @HarshPokharna That's not the idea behind fragments, but you can make it that way. The idea is not to have multiple activities, only multiple fragments, that you can swap in and out your main activity.

Comment: @HarshPokharna Here is a complete tutorial on how to set up tabs. http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#tabsIt makes use of fragments, which i think is the only way to implement tabs, but i might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

check [jfeinstein10 's sliding menu on github](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) its the best sliding menu you can find , and there is a detailed description on how to use it as a library to add it in your app.

moreover you can find related question and answers here at SO.

to set it only in tab A , you can declare it inside the class where tab A is initiated , and set its length as you want.

just take into consideration that you have to import it as a library and use it into you project.

good luck